# Remove trailing slashes in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I found this snippet in one of the other stack overflow questions.

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector, $location){
  let path = $location.path();
  let hasTrailingSlash = path[path.length-1] === '/';
  if(hasTrailingSlash) {
    console.log('coming in the has trailing slash rule function');
    let normalizedPath = path.substr(0, path.length - 1);
    $location.replace().path(normalizedPath);
  }
});
```

I have some urls in the following forms `/school/:id`, `/school`, `/:id`, `/class/:id`

The above function works perfectly fine if I enter a url in the form `/class/121/` and it redirects to `/class/121`, similarly `/about-us/` redirects to `/about-us`. But when I enter `/school/` I get a 404 error. According to this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing

> '/user/:id' - Matches '/user/bob' or '/user/1234!!!' or even '/user/' but not '/user' or '/user/bob/details'. The second path segment will be captured as the parameter 'id'

So I am guessing it goes to the `/school/:id` state, note in such a case, `$urlRouterProvider.rule` is not called. Some sample defined modules

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {
    'ngInject';
    $stateProvider
        .state('school', {
    hasLefSideMenu: true,

            url: '/school/:id',
            templateUrl: '/school/school.html',
            controller: 'SchoolController',
            reloadOnSearch: false,
            controllerAs: 'schoolCtrl'
        });
})



.config(function($stateProvider) {
'ngInject';

$stateProvider
  .state('all-school', {
    hasLefSideMenu: true,

    url: '/school',
    templateUrl: '/all-schools.html',
    controller: 'allSchoolsController',
    controllerAs: 'allSchoolsCtrl'
  });
```

})

Ideally for all urls trailing slash should be removed. Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

`$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false)`

described [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes)